# Azure Data Factory Pipelines API: Cannot apply filters

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory

The issue might be trivial, but I cannot find out what am I doing wrong. I am trying to check whether there are any "in progress" runs of a specific pipeline within my data factory. The below call gives me a full list of all runs in my ADF (correct):'

[image]

However, the very moment I add either a filter on a pipeline name, or a filter on status, the results are empty. Even though there are valid runs that should be returned.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we are talking about the same API then the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP#request-body) said that lastUpdatedAfter and lastUpdatedBefore are required fields in the body.

Take note of the format of these dates in the example Microsoft provides:

```
{
  "lastUpdatedAfter": "2018-06-16T00:36:44.3345758Z",
  "lastUpdatedBefore": "2018-06-16T00:49:48.3686473Z",
  "filters": [
    {
      "operand": "PipelineName",
      "operator": "Equals",
      "values": [
        "examplePipeline"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```